# independent lighting per mesh in blender

Tags: blender, lighting

In Blender, is it possible to assign lighting objects/effects exclusively to a single mesh? For instance, if I place two meshes next to each other, and two lights (one shining on each mesh), I would want each mesh to **not** cast a cast any shadow on the other.

For example, in the following rendered image from a "test" star system view:

[image: unwanted shadows]

The rings are casting shadows on the right-most planets. I want the rings to **only** cast shadows on their own planet.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a long time since I tried this. but basically in blender lighting is only applied on one given layer. So to get lighting for individual objects, you need to put each on it's own layer with one light.

P.S I first thought about "not casting shadows", but that probably won't work, since you may want self shadowing. (-> rings)

Comment: Looks like this is exactly the answer. It's even in the docs, once I search the web for "blender render multiple layers": http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/Layers ("Sometimes the artist... does not want lights for one object to affect nearby objects"). Awesome! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.